# Using up raw chicken with freezer burn - how to cook to make the best of it

Tags: frozen, chicken-breast

I froze a spare chicken breast raw, to save for my daughter (I very rarely eat meat, she has a bit more, but they come in packs of 2). I noticed it's got visible freezer burn.  *I refuse to waste it*, so I'm going to eat it myself; after all, it's perfectly safe.

Normally I'd stir-fry chicken breast with veg, and add a sauce.  I know from past experience that it can end up rather tough in that case.  Can I do better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still save this breast if you:

- [Use a velveting technique](https://thewoksoflife.com/how-to-velvet-chicken-stir-fry/) to give it a silky texture and help retain moisture when you stir fry it
- boil in broth and shred it (for a salad or a soup, for example) - I don't think the difference in texture will be noticeable
- season it and cook it sous-vide to 63.3ºC (145.9F) for 1:30h, it's the method that will probably result in the most moist chicken of all methods.

Comment: All good advice, I'd add trimming off the obviously freezer-burned parts, they could add off-flavors.

Comment: Also, you can boil it in just enough salsa to cover it, then reduce the liquid down until your left with a tender and spicy shredded chicken that's perfect for tacos or burritos.

Comment: @KnotWright yeah: broth / salsa / sauce etc there are plenty of ways to add flavor!

Comment: I can confirm the second one. I had some freezer burned chicken recently, made chicken noodle soup with it, and didn't even notice the difference.